Are B9 and F9 a tritone substitition?
Could you explain this chord progression to me?  A7 B9 F9 B (dyad root and major third) Gbm C#7 A/C# D Dmaj7 Bm7 E7 A7?

Where's it from? The Gbm ought to be F#m, I guess.

I am going to simply answer your title question but not talk about the analysis of your chord progressions because those types of questions are not answered on this site.
B9 and F9 are best referred to as B7 and F7 because the upper extensions like 9, 11 and 13 are usually not that important for analysis. Those two chords by themselves are just two dominant chords that are a tritone apart.
However, if you think of B7 as a V7 chord resolving to an E chord, then F7 is your bII7, and F7 is a tritone substitution of B7.
The same as true in reverse, but with an enharmonic adjustment. If F7 is your V7 chord resolving to a Bb chord, then Cb7 is your bII7 tritone substitution. The reason for the enharmonic adjustment is that the substitution must be a bII7, Cb7-Bb not a #I7 B7-Bb.

No tts. As the notes involved in B9 are B, D♯, F♯, A and C♯, while F9 contains F, A, C, E♭ and G. The whole set of notes for one chord, whilst sounding good together, doesn't make the other whole set sound like a good substitution.
The whole point of tts is that the ^3 and ^7 change over with each other. In the case of B7 and F7, it's the A and the D♯/E♭. The 9th part of each chord messes things up - neither belong in the other chord.
An interesting slant is that F7♭5 and B7♭5 are subs for each other - in 12tet, they contain exactly the same four notes!

Weird, this actually looks like a decent argument that the F9 is a TTS for a B7 chord instead of your claim that no TTS's are included. Your "neither belong in the other chord" statement also applies to half the notes of other TTS, such as the D flat and A flat in Db7 vs. the G and D in its TTS, G7.

@Dekkadeci - with another extra note ( against 4) in a 9th chord, I stand by. If you could put your argument for TTS in an answer, maybe it'll throw more light on the situation, as no-one else has come up with much, so far.
